# How to write to beginning of file using open(fileName, 'a+')

Tags: python, file-io

I am using

```
excelFile = open(fileName, 'a+')
```

To open a file and append data to it (append is critical). I am writing a lot of lines to the file, about 1/second, while also doing some calculations (integrating each variable over time). At the end of writing all of these lines I would like to go to the top of the file and write the summary for each variable.

It would look like this:

> **Battery Energy In, Motor Energy Out, Odometer, Something else...**
>
> 100, 50, 527km, ...
>
> **Battery Power In, Motor Power Out, Speed, ...**
>
> 10, 5, 20
>
> 20, 4, 22
>
> ... 86,398 more lines

However, that doesn't seem to be an option because anytime I use seek() to move the cursor, the write() still happens at the end of the file.

Can this be done without having to iterate over each line to calculate and write the summary, and then iterate over it again to write the lines below it?

Comment: Are you aware that writing to the beginning of the file will overwrite the content of the file and NOT move the existing content? Let's say you have the file with content 'abcdefg'. If you write 'hij' to the beginning of the file, the new file content will be 'hijdefg'. I just want to make sure if that's what you want.

Comment: I would like to write two blank lines at the start, and then fill those in when I'm done all my summing.

Comment: But the file has no notion of `line`. The content is composed of bytes. A line is only marked by linefeed character(s). Two blank lines are 2 bytes on Unix and 4 bytes on Windows. Having content in separate lines is just the way that file viewer software interprets linefeed characters.

Comment: Having this said, can you estimate the maximum length (in bytes) of summary lines?

Comment: Yes, and I feel comfortable filling it with whitespace, that's no problem for me. Thanks! Would I have to use the r+ mode of writing then and manually create the file and seek the beginning/end for each of my operations?

Comment: Yes, if you know how many whitespace characters you need, proceed with `r+` as Martijn Pieters wrote. Write whitespace first, then data and finally `seek(0)` to overwrite whitespace with the summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some operating systems limit files opened in append mode to only write to the end of the file.

Open the file in `'r+'` (read/write) mode instead. Take into account that the file position then starts at 0.

Comment: You're suggesting I close the file after writing all of the lines. Open it again, and then write the summary lines since the pointer will be at the top? If that works, it's good enough for me!

Comment: @jules0075: no, I'm not suggesting anything like that. `r+` opens the file for both reading and writing. You can then seek anywhere in the file, write to that position, or read  from that position, at will.